# How to join 2 tables using sql statements in PHP and fetch all the datas of a specific row?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$customer= $_GET['customer'];
// Prepare the query that will be executed
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT codes.customer AS customer
                          , codes.views AS views, order.plan AS plan 
                       FROM codes INNER JOIN order ON codes.customerid=order.id 
                       WHERE codes.customer = $");
$stmt->execute();
```

The above code shows error. How do i fetch the datas of the specific row where `codes.customer = Rahul`.

Comment: in the join you use register.id, but there is no register and order is reserved in most database try escape it to 'order'

Comment: The $ should be inside of a quote (like '$') and this is one error (among other errors that may exist).

Comment: @tano that was actually 'order'. I should change order to another variable. thanks.

Comment: @AliKhalili fixing that removes the error. Now how to fetch data views, plan of that $customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a prepared statement, which is the way to go to prevent a possible SQL injection attack. But one way to do that is as follows:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT codes.customer AS customer,
                          codes.views AS views, order.plan AS plan 
                       FROM codes INNER JOIN order ON codes.customerid=order.id 
                       WHERE codes.customer = :");
$stmt->bindValue(":customer", $customer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); /* fetch all rows */
/* or $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); */ /* fetch one row */
foreach($rows as &$row) {
    echo 'customer = ', $row['customer'], ', views = ', $row['views'], ', plan = ', $row['plan'], "\n";
}
```

Comment: How do I echo out the views, and plan? When i do that it shows nothing.. when i echo $rows it just shows 'Array' and when i echo '$row' it shows nothing..

Comment: First, you do either `fetchAll` to get all the rows (there might be only one) or `fetch` but not both because once you do `fetchAll` doing `fetch` will not return anything because all the rows have already been returned by `fetchAll`. Easiest way to display might be `print_r($rows);`. Of course, `echo $rows[0]['views'];` to display the views in the first row returned.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how to output all the returned rows.

Comment: There is a lot of substance in the above code that needs to be understood thoroughly. It may be time to look at tutorials on doing MySql queries using PDO. It couldn't hurt also to review basic PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Really helped me a lot.